# Configuring bamboo to run automated test using appium cucumber in Android

Tags: android, cucumber, bamboo, appium

I am creating a sample android application to run automated test case using Appium + Cucumber. My source code is in [**GitHub**](https://github.com/npanigrahy/Appium_android). It compiles and runs in command prompt, which confirms me that the all environmental settings and installations are fine.

I am running below command to execute test case

```
cucumber features/login.feature
or 
cucumber
```

It failed, while I am trying to configure the same thing on bamboo. But below is the error from bamboo

```
10-Jul-2014 10:03:58    Starting task 'run cucu' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.scripttask:task.builder.script'
10-Jul-2014 10:03:58    
Beginning to execute external process for build 'AutomatedUI - Appium_Android - Build and Instal #92 (AUT-AP-JOB1-92)'
 ... running command line: 
/bin/sh /Applications/Bamboo/temp/AUT-AP-JOB1-92-ScriptBuildTask-8977016011738507175.sh
 ... in: /Users/Admin/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/AUT-AP-JOB1
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    /Users/Admin/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/AUT-AP-JOB1/features/support/env.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    ...= Appium.load_appium_txt file: File.expand_path('./', __FILE...
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01                                  ^ (SyntaxError)
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load'
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load_code_file'
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in `load_step_definitions'
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/bin/cucumber:13
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    /usr/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    /usr/bin/cucumber:19
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    Failing task since return code of [/bin/sh /Applications/Bamboo/temp/AUT-AP-JOB1-92-ScriptBuildTask-8977016011738507175.sh] was 1 while expected 0
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    Finished task 'run cucu'
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    Running post build plugin 'Clover Results Collector'
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    Running post build plugin 'Artifact Copier'
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    Running post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
10-Jul-2014 10:04:01    Finalising the build...
```

Need your inputs to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out to fix this issue.

The "cucumber" command is not working directly. I have created a "rake" file and executed the rake file. For executing the rake, directly from bamboo, you need to download the ruby add on.

**[Download Link](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/au.id.wolfe.bamboo.rake-bamboo-plugin/versions)**

**[Adon Documentation](https://github.com/wolfeidau/rake-bamboo-plugin)**

For code sample, you may visit my [Github repo](https://github.com/npanigrahy/Appium_android).